# What core functionality can't be modified?

Tags: magento-1.8

A customer asked me how flexible Magento is. I tend to say you can change everything you like even without changing any core files. But I am not sure about this maybe I am missing something. As far as I know you can modify all HTML output with templates. Using modules you can add and remove columns and tables from the database. Also you can overwrite Magento core file with modules or in bad practice with `app/local/Mage/`. So I think you can change a Magento until there is no core function left except maybe `index.php`.

So my question is:

What Magento core functionality can't be modified without directly changing core files?

Comment: How is this opinion-based? You can customize a feature or you can not. I don't think there is much to argue about.

Comment: This is opinion-based because you don't describe a specific problem. You refer to Magento in general. It's like asking "how good is this hammer". If you want to nail something to the wall is pretty good (but may depend on what you want to nail). If you want to destroy a wall, it may be good (but it depends on the thickness of the wall). If you want to cook with it, is (almost) useless. (Sorry for the analogy, I couldn't find a better one fast). Explain exactly what you need and you might get a valid answer.

Comment: @Marius Thank you, I think I see what you mean and changed my question. Now we have a fixed set of core function and the question which one of those can't be overwritten without directly touching the core files. There should be not much room for opinions left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, everything can be changed.

But practically, you will often run into things which you will want to tell the client as things that cannot be changed.

In most cases this will be because changing that would require too much costs for comparatively much lesser benefit. These costs can be anything from money to time or your programming skills. For eg. theoretically you can build a simple blog in magento, but it's not something that you will want to do.

Overall it all comes to what you want to achieve. My suggestion is that you should try working on changing things & ask questions about "How to do this? How to do that?" & that will give you a much better idea of what magento can & cannot do?